# How to goto() an array of URLs with Nightmare.js JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nightmare

I'm getting an array of `URLs` returned. How do i loop through the array and use [nightmare](/questions/tagged/nightmare)`goto()` function you go to each URL and execute [nightmare](/questions/tagged/nightmare)code then close and do the next one?

Heres my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');

vo(function*() {
  var nightmare = Nightmare();
  var title = yield nightmare
    .goto('https://www.example.com/l/los_angeles-california')
    .inject('js', `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`)
    .evaluate(function() {
      var hrefs = [];
      $('.ItemsListCard').find('a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
      });

      return hrefs //array of urls

      for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
        nightmare.goto(hrefs[i].href)
          .wait(5000)
          .click('.ItemListingActionButtons')
          .type('.ThreadViewInput__input', 'Hey! ')
          .click('.ThreadViewInput__send')
      }

    });
  console.log(title);
  yield nightmare.end();

})(function(err, result) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a difference between code you're asking Nightmare to execute (via `.execute()`) in the browser context, and code you're running in the controller in nodejs. You have the right idea here, but after returning `hrefs`, the rest of the code to iterate over them should be in the controller, like so:

```
const hrefs = yield nightmare
    .goto('https://www.example.com/l/los_angeles-california')
    .inject('js', `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`)
    .evaluate(function() {
      var hrefs = [];
      $('.ItemsListCard').find('a').each(function() {
        hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
      });

      return hrefs; //array of urls
    });
for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
   yield nightmare.goto(hrefs[i].href)
     .wait(5000)
     .click('.ItemListingActionButtons')
     .type('.ThreadViewInput__input', 'Hey! ')
     .click('.ThreadViewInput__send');
}
```